# Accessing helper clone of draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am applying `.draggable()` with `helper: clone` to an element. I also have droppable elements. Events triggered by any of the droppable elements fire a callback with signature

```
function (event, ui)
```

Within this function, `$(this)` refers to the droppable element, and `ui.draggable` to the draggable element (*not* the helper clone).

How can I access the helper clone from within the callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ui.helper` does the job. Shame it's not well documented. Had to inspect the source.

Comment: It is in fact documented, but perhaps not very well (as in not easily discoverable): http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Aha, well spotted! Should probably be documented in the API documentation, not in the demos section.

Comment: agreed, but...do they even have an API doco available? I always find their documentation hard to find. I often have to dig things out like you did for this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in the callback method.

```
var helper = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "helper" );
```

Where `.selector` is the element on which you have applied the `draggable` plugin.

Comment: No, actually. This is just the getter for the `helper` option, not the actual element. So in this case it just returns the string `clone` because I have `helper: clone`.